Do the $\ell^{\infty}$ and $\ell^1$ norms yield minimal doubling constants amongst all norms on $\mathbb{R}^n$?
Setting:
Let $X:=\mathbb{R}^n$ for some positive integer $n$.  For each $1\le p\le \infty$ let $d_p$ denote the metric induced by the $\ell^p_n$ norm thereon.
Note that, the doubling constant of a metric space $(X,d)$ is the smallest number $C>0$ such that: for every $x\in X$ and each $r>0$ the ball of radius $2r$ at $x$ can be covered by at-most $\lceil C\rceil $ balls of radius $r$.
Motivation:
As discussed in this post, in 2, a good bound on the doubling constant of $(X,d_2)$ is computed.  One immediately sees that this is much looser than the doubling constant on $(X,d_{\infty})$ which is $2^n$.
Intuitively, it seems that the issue is that, for $1<p<\infty$, ellipsoids do not pack/fit together perfectly, while boxes/diamonds do (not certain about the $p=1$ case in "high dimensions" when $n>2$).

Questions:
Motivated by these observations, out of pure curiosity (as we most are), my questions are:

Main Curiosity: Does $d_{\infty}$ achieve the smallest doubling constants amongst all metrics induced by norms on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

As a bonus, I was also wondering:

Pure-pure Curiosity: Does there exist a metric $d^{\star}$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ which is equivalent to $d_{\infty}$ but for which $(X,d^{\star})$ has a smaller doubling constant?  If so, does a $d^{\star}$ achieving a minimal doubling constant look like?

My intuition is that, such a $d^{\star}$ must somehow have minimal "ball volume" at "all scales".

Can you solve $\mathbb R^2$ ?

I can't tbh, but I know of bounds; typically standard ones seem to be $2^{2n+1}$ as in Robinson's book: https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/dimensions-embeddings-and-attractors/3C621DA218BE433CEC5B0E9C558286F8 (unless I made a silly typo due to too much loud music)

Why $d_1$?  $(\mathbb{R}^2,d_1)$ is isometric to  $(\mathbb{R}^2,d_\infty)$, but this is not true for $\mathbb{R}^n$ with $n\ge 3$.

Ah, okay, I indeed thought of $\mathbb{R}^2$ for the $d_1$ case.  Let me fix that.  Thanks Anton :)

Does not this follow simply from counting the covered volume?

That is minimal (amongst norms or all equivalent metrics)?   I don't see how (at-least I don't)

Perhaps include the definition of "doubling constant" in the question.

@GeraldEdgar Done :)
